# How to reset a pandas dataframe data types to default or auto detect?

Tags: pandas

Is it possible to reset a dataframe dtypes to default or auto detected ones (e.g., to detect and match strings and numbers) after they have been set manually? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html):

> Attempt to infer better dtype for object columns

*This will work well e.g. if you've made it of object dtype, but this certainly isn't a magic bullet.*

Comment: pandas 0.19.2 says this is depreciated.

Comment: @Selah yes, to_numeric, to_datetime, to_timedelta see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#object-conversion. It is sad to see it be deprecated but understandable as it hit a lot of magic (there is some talk of bringing it back - I can't find the github issue), usually it is better to be explicit.